# Error when using ModalRoute to retrieve arguments, settings was called on null

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to send a path of a file from on screen to another and using navigator for passing the file path as argument but it is showing me error that setting was called on null.
thanks

Push

```
onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("MyApp", arguments: {
            'path': _songs[i],
            });
          },
```

Extraction

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final routes =
 ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, File>;
```

Error

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#e3c46):
The getter 'settings' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: settings
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MyApp 
package:MusicApp/main.dart:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of this:

```
final routes = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, File>;
```

try this:

```
final Map<String, dynamic> routes = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```